# Obtain a tempered distribution from $1/|x|$ by subtracting a multiple of $\phi(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to show that for an appropriate choice of constants $c_{\delta}$ which diverge as $\delta \to 0$ a distribution $W\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ can be defined by:
$$ W(\phi)=\lim_{\delta \to 0}\,\int_{|x|>\delta} \bigg(\frac{1}{|x|}\phi(x)-c_{\delta}\phi(0)\bigg)\,dx \,\,\,\,\, \phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$$

I am new to distributions and I am finding them a bit confusing, we first have to show that this defines a linear functional on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and clearly the only thing to prove here is that the limit converges. Then do we prove that the above satisfies the necessary and sufficient boundedness/continuity condition to lie in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ or can we prove the latter first to save time without knowing the integral makes sense?

So we have to show that we can choose constants $\delta$ so that the integral converges independently of $\delta$? I have been looking at 
$$\bigg|\frac{\phi(x)-(c_{\delta}|x|)\phi(0)}{x}\bigg|$$

and have been trying to use the differentiability of $\phi$ but I'm not sure this will work.

Answer (score 3):

The starting point is that the limit $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\,\int_{\delta<|x|<1} \frac{1}{|x|}(\phi(x)- \phi(0))\,dx\tag1$$
is finite, because the integrand is  bounded  by the Mean Value Theorem : $|\phi(x)- \phi(0)|\le |x|\sup |\phi'|$.

This tells you what $c_\delta$ should be: it's $-2\log\delta$.

To complete the proof that this is a distribution, you need continuity with respect to $\phi$. This will follow from the estimate
$$W(\phi)\le C(\sup|\phi'| + \sup (|x|+1) |\phi(x)|)$$
because the suprema on the left bound (1) together: one helps for $|x|<1$, the other for $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: Hi, having thought about your answer in more detail I am puzzled to how you obtain those constants. To me it is not clear that the integral will converge, wouldn't the constants need to oscillate between positive and negative values?